# Get parameters in macro without type

Tags: c++

I want to define a macro which defines a function and in the body passes the arguments to another, such as:

```
#define FUNC(return_type, name, ...) \
    return_type name(__VA_ARGS__)\
    {\
        something_else(__VA_ARGS__ without types);\
    }
```

For example,

```
FUNC(bool, do_something, int a, bool b, float c);
```

would equate to

```
bool do_something(int a, bool b, float c)
{
    something_else(a, b, c);
}
```

I currently solve this problem using inline assembly, which gives VS debugger issues and is not an acceptable solution

Comment: This is not something you can do with macros. Consider using a variadic template function instead (which you should be using anyway)

Comment: Could you please explain why you cannot simply pass the arguments directly into the something_else function? On its own, this function seems completely pointless.

Comment: I am calling a virtual function, only given a pointer to the interface and the index of the virtual function.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using macros for this. You could write a function template that can be used to generate the appropriate function for you:

```
template<typename Ret, typename ...Args>
Ret FUNC(Args ...args) {
    return something_else(args...); 
}
```

which is used like this:

```
auto do_something = FUNC<bool,int,bool,float>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/F3gV_5)

Comment: In your example, there is nothing for the lambda to capture, so there is no need to use `[&]` in the capture list, `[]` will suffice.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Found a simpler solution that doesn't need a lambda at all :)

Comment: This is nice, however I should have been more specific. I would like to preserve the argument names somehow.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. May I ask why? What do the names matter really? But if they do, you should update your question with a use case, because as it stands, they aren't needed.